# Bootstrap - Display mobile menu at 992px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

at the moment my navbar only displays a mobile menu on smaller devices. I want it to display when the viewport is smaller than 992px.

Here is a fiddle of my navbar: http://jsfiddle.net/nickmadd/DTcHh/574/

As you can see there are actually two navbars due to the fact I couldn't make the desktop version responsive in the way I wanted it to be.

So when the viewport hits 992px how can I make the 'mini nav' display a tabbed mobile version like it does when it is scaled right down?

Here is my mobile navbar html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default nav-links navbar-fixed-top hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="visible-sm visible-xs navbar-toggle" data-target="#i-want-this-to-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
      <a class="mini-navbar navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="media/img/nav-logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales Logo" class="img-rounded logo-nav mini-navbar" />
      </a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Used Cars</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Get Finance</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Driven<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li> <a href "#">The Team</a>
          </li>
          <li> <a href "#">Our Partners</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">How To Find Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any tips would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the below mentioned code in [JS Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/urYbJ/).

You just have to add few lines of code in the stylesheet.

```
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    /*body {display: none;}*/
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav {
        clear: both;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

If you have any other queries or comments, then please modify the JS Fiddle, and write your comment. I hope I can help you in that.

Regards D.

Comment: Best solution is change scss  _variables_ *@grid-float-breakpoint* <br/> 

`$grid-float-breakpoint:     $screen-md-min !default;`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using less, customize the **@grid-float-breakpoint**.  If you aren't you can use the [**Customize**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page to modify the value and produce a custom css file.  To have the collapse at the 992px breakpoint, change the value to: **@screen-md-min**.

Customize page:

[image]

Alternatively, you can create your own media query.

Comment: You can also use this in LESS. I use LESS as my source for compiling rather than the customize page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correct, then you want to adjust when bootstrap registeres different sizes of the screen...

Have a look at the customization when you're downloading Bootstrap. If you scroll down to the Media Query Breakpoints (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) then you'll be able to your variables there :)